# Equivalent of [globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0] with symfony expression language?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

How can I check if a page is a single view (ie for news) with the newly integrated symfony expression language in typoscript? I am searching for the equivalent of:

`[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it:

```
[request.getQueryParams()['tx_news_pi1']['news'] > 0]
```

Comment: In TYPO3 10 LTS this will create an error in the error log each time a page is called without these get parameters (not testet in 9 LTS). I have seen a logfile grow to > 1 GB in a short time. The answer of Julian Hofmann with "traverse" is better, because it does not produce an error.

Answer (score 7):

```
[traverse(request.getQueryParams(), 'tx_news_pi/news') > 0]
# This condition matches if current query parameters have tx_news_pi[news] set to a value greater than zero
[END]
```

(https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.4/Feature-85829-ImplementSymfonyExpressionLanguageForTypoScriptConditions.html#general-usage)

Comment: Use tx_news_pi1 instead of tx_news_pi.